# PHP curl returns error: Couldn't resolve host 'www.xxx.com'. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

this function returns null and prints error :

Couldn't resolve host 'www.xxx.com'

```
function file_get_html_using_cURL($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        echo "\n--------------------\n";
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo "\n--------------------\n";
    }
    $output = str_get_html($output); // <-- Important line to convert string into object!
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

When I load this code in localhost, it works. But it throws the error when I upload it to the remote server.

I  am guessing that the remote server has blocked CURL from executing.

It's a free server so I can't change any settings in php.ini

Is there any way around this?

P.S.

```
file_get_content($url)
```

is blocked as well. So I tried using curl instead. But not curl doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: are you able to ping any host?ping google.com? If not then edit /etc/resolv.conf and place a line nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: I think its issue with your dns.. contact your system administrator and check firewall

Comment: @ChetanAmeta The server administrator said php curl should work fine. Here is the PHP settings.  112.175.184.89/phptest.php
Is it something unrelated to DNS? Sorry i am a beginner..

Comment: try to ping domain on server's terminal also try after turning off firewall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL curl\_exec returns "Couldn't resolve host "www.~.com". Is CURL enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303394/php-curl-curl-exec-returns-couldnt-resolve-host-www-com-is-curl-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code and verify your server issue.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOUR_URL' );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );

var_dump(curl_exec($curl));
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
var_dump(curl_error($curl));
```