# PHP CURL curl_exec returns "Couldn't resolve host "www.~.com". Is CURL enabled?

Tags: php, curl

This function works on localhost, but not on my remote server.

I inquired the server master about this, and it told me PHP CURL is enabled and things should work fine.

And here is the code:

the $url that I am testing with is:

```
$url = "http://bus.go.kr/getSubway_6.jsp?statnId=1003000323&subwayId=1003"
```

Here is the function:

```
function file_get_html_using_cURL($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, faslse);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);



    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        echo "\n--------------------\n";
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo "\n--------------------\n";
    }

    $output = str_get_html($output); // <-- Important line to convert string into object!
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

And this is what returns on the site page:

```
Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'bus.go.kr'
--------------------
Array
(
[url] => http://bus.go.kr/getSubway_6.jsp?statnId=1003000323&subwayId=1003
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

)

--------------------
```

I have no clue why this isn't working on the remote server.

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure, Is curl enable on your machine?

Comment: Wow. You just published the IP address of server running ancient, unsupported PHP 5.3.3 that probably contains a bunch of open security issues. Please remove this machine from the internet!

Comment: This reads like an issue with name resolution on that system.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks. i removed the IP address, but it was a free server anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` is enabled and works perfectly in your case. Unfortunately, the server where it runs cannot resolve the name `bus.go.kr`. Resolving in this context means finding the IP address of an Internet host whose name is known.

There can be many sources for the problem. If it's permanent then the server is probably misconfigured. If it's temporary then it's probably a connectivity issue.

You can do more checks with different URLs, http://www.google.com for example, and see what results you get. If you cannot reach any of them then it's a configuration problem.

Comment: It is also possible that it needs to use a proxy to work.

Comment: by using $url = "http://www.google.com" returns "Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'". Is this configuration problem then? Can you teach me how and what to change in the configuration?

Comment: It's not something wrong with PHP, it is at the OS level. You should ask the system admin.

Comment: As @DanielStenberg suggests, it's possible that you need to send your requests to a proxy as the server where your code runs seems to not have direct access to the Internet. You can find if this is the case (and what is the name/address of the proxy server) by asking your system admin. Then you have to add `curl` options related to `CURLOPT_PROXY` to your code.

Answer (score -1):

try to use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: Please could edit your answer to explain why this behaves differently to that in the question?